# Google checkout not available in my country, how can i publicate paid apps in GooglePlay?

Tags: android, google-checkout

Sadly in my country GoogleCheckout not available. I want to make a paid app, i already started it but its not that good that i wont be able to upload it to GooglePlay as a paid app, only free.

Is there any way, or any sollution to somehow make a checkout account and publicate from other country or something else?

Comment: wouldn't that be illegal and/or breaking Google TOS and rules?

Comment: I would like to shine some light on that part too. Is it completly illegal just because i live in Hungary ?

Answer (score 3):

Is AdSense available in your country? For some countries you may be able to sell apps on Google Play and receive Google Checkout payments through AdSense.

See this link for more information:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189263

Comment: It is for Argentina, Brazil, Russia, and Taiwan. 
Im from Hungary, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but I'll try answering in case it helps anyone else.

I don't know if this will work, but it fixes similar problems when you want to download content not available in your country. It let me download Google Wallet which was previously unavailable to me.

Let me stress, I don't know about the legal issues! I used this fix when I actually relocated and needed to change my location in Google Play.

You'll need a credit card with a US billing address (or any other country in which the content you need is available). You'll also need a Google Wallet account.

1) Sign into your Google Wallet account to manage your payment methods https://wallet.google.com/manage/paymentMethods

2) Add a new card or change your default payment instrument to one with a billing address located in your desired country

3) Open the Play Store and navigate to any item available for download

4) Click to begin a download until you reach the "Accept and buy" screen (no need to complete the purchase). You should now see that the currency has changed to the currency of your desired country

5) Close the Play Store and clear your browser cache. On Android phones  Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Clear Data

6) Re-open the Play Store. You should now see the Play Store that matches your default payment instrument's billing country. On my phone this didn't happen right away but took a few minutes. I tried to shop for a phone available in the US (Nexus 4) and now saw it's available.

Comment: I want to publicate a paid app, not to download :-) but thanks anyway